# behavior of let and const with javascript 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, this

```
var num = 8;

const wantToKnowThis = function(val) {
  var num = 6;
  return this.num
}
console.log(wantToKnowThis(3));
```

if i run this code the answer will be 8 and that is correct but if run this code by just replacing let or const, it will give undefined!!

```
let num = 8;

const wantToKnowThis = function(val) {
  var num = 6;
  return this.num
}
console.log(wantToKnowThis(3));
```

is let and const behave diffrent with this keyword than var does please let me know??

Comment: Do you think they are both aliases of `var`?

Comment: Both your code samples are identical, and the `val` parameter is never used

Comment: There’s a good explanation of the difference in scoping between `let` and `var` on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2)

Comment: @ADyson the code blocks were exchanged, so that is my mistake

Comment: @MTCoster thanks for sharing this i am new with javascript so  'this' keyword telling me somthing new everytime  i tried to code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `var` in the global scope, then it will implicitly create a property of the same name on the `window` object.

The same is not true of `const` or `let`.

---

This doesn't really have anything to do with `this` other than at a couple of steps removed.

If you use `this` is a function with no context (i.e. which is not a method on an object and hasn't got a bound context via `bind` or `=>`), then `this` will be `window` (unless you use `"use strict"` and you should always use `"use strict"` as it prevents all kinds of gotchas)

---

If you want to access a variable outside of the function you are in then don't resort to global variable shenanigans. Simply **don't give a local variable the same name in the first place**.

```js
let num = 8;

const wantToKnowThis = function(val) {
  let local_num = 6;
  return num;
}

console.log(wantToKnowThis(3));
```

Comment: actually i did not know that at global scope let and const, unlike var, does not create property on window/global object